# My user isn't deleted

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database table called users, and I've managed to see all of the users information. The next step for me is to delete a record. And I find it hard to do, since I'm using objects.

I call a list of my users like this:

```
echo $db->getUsers ();
```

I instantiate my object in my init file:

```
 $db = new DB_con ();
```

And in my DB_con class I call my function getUsers

```
public function getUsers() {
        $str = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = $this->mysqli->query ( $str );
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $string = "<table><thead><tr><th>id</th><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Email</th><th>Role</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                $string .= "<tr><td>" . $row ['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['first_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['last_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['role_id'] . "</td><td>  [<a href='delete.php?id=" . $row ['id'] . "'>Delete</a>]</td></tr>";
            }
            $string .= "</tbody></table>";
            return $string;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I create a link that can look like this fx: delete.php?id=13

In my delete.php file i have the following:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
echo $id;
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

But my users's aren't deleted. I really hope someone can help me out. And please ask, if I need to supply you with more code.

Comment: Your `getUsers()` class implies the use of `mysqli`, but your delete function calls `mysql_query()`, which is not compatible with mysqli.

Comment: It is _essential_ that you start learning [to use `prepare()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in MySQLi. Your delete function is vulnerable to SQL injection, and any user could trivially delete _all_ your users in one go.

Comment: [`Which translates to`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920794/my-user-isnt-deleted#comment34985870_22920794) => `$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);` <= EDIT

Comment: SQL vulnerability is wide, you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@MichaelBerkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) already pointed out you're mixing `mysql_*` library with `mysqli` which is not good and could possible be where your issue is given you do not have an already established connection using `mysql_*` library.

You could add the following function to your `DB_con` class which use prepared statement and will be by **default protecting you against SQL Injection:

```
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    if (!$result = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$result->bind_param('i', $id))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $result->execute();
}
```

And call it as `$db->deleteUser($_GET['id']);` no need to use `intval`, so you could use like this:

```
if ($db->deleteUser($_GET['id']))
{
    echo "User has been deleted!";
}
else
{
    echo "Could not delete the user!";
}
```

**** only on the above given function!**

Comment: Thank you very much. This will also set me up, for when I need to update my records. And thanks for pointing out that I was mixing mysql_* library with mysqli.